# Table does not display in List of Tables

Tags: tables, csv, csvsimple

I'm including a table:

```
\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\csvautotabular{results.csv}
\caption{Results}
\end{table}
```

And in the top of my document, I have:

```
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

However, all of the figures I include do display in List of Figures, but this table does not, even though it has a caption.

Edit: Here is a working example. Strangely, it works in this example, but not in my longer .tex file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage {csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
    \csvautotabular{results.csv}
    \caption{Results}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

where `results.csv` is any `.csv` file.

Comment: Did you make sure to run twice?

Comment: Yes, running twice does not change anything.

Comment: is there an entry for `\@writefile{lot}` in your `.aux` file?

Comment: Yes, there is that entry there.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the OP.

Comment: Does the just posted MWE create a list entry? What happens if you comment out the csv-line?

Comment: Yes, it still has a list entry if I comment out the line (and run twice).

Comment: I am a bit confused now. In the question you are expecting the table in the list of figures (noted that just now, could be a typo). No you say, it (the table?) *has* a list entry. Please explain in more detail, what you see and what you expect.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant that in my actual .tex document (much longer than the example given), I have both list of figures and list of tables, where LoF does have a list entry, and LoT does not. The list entry I mean refers to the example.

Comment: do you use `\include` ?

Comment: An example which is supposed to show the cause but doesn't is quite useless. Make a backup of your files and then start to comment out stuff till the reason is obvious. Might take a few minutes, but it is the only way to find the cause. If you don't see the cause yourself, post your minimal example.

Comment: I had the same problem, but turned out that I forgot to reference the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was not doing anything wrong. Apparently there is a bug where this can happen.

The solution I found was to comment out all of the `\include{section_file.tex}` includes I had, and one-by-one uncomment them, and (doubly) compile the main `.tex` file. And that solves the problem!